# Closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: general-topology

The Heine-Borel Theorem states that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are compact. I think this implies that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are also compact. However, I could not write the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer: there is a clear $\Bbb C\cong\Bbb R^2$ isometry, a $\Bbb C^n\cong\Bbb R^{2n}$ isometry. So closed and bounded subsets of one turn into closed and bounded subsets of the other, and you can use Heine-Borel (regular version) immediately.

There is also a general Heine-Borel-esque theorem for metric spaces.

> If $(X,\rho)$ is a complete and totally bounded metric space, then it is compact.

Bounded subsets of $\Bbb R^n$, and $\Bbb C^n$, are also totally bounded. As $\Bbb C^n,\Bbb R^n$ are always complete, any closed subset thereof forms a complete metric subspace: it follows that bounded, closed subsets form compact subspaces. Compactness is absolute, so that means they are compact subsets!

> $(X,\rho)$ is a totally bounded metric space if, for all $\varepsilon>0$, an $\varepsilon$-net can be found: a **finite** set of points $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^n\subseteq X$ such that: $$X=\bigcup_{j=1}^nB_\rho(x_j,\varepsilon)$$

To see this for the $n$-Euclidean spaces is not too hard. You take a fine lattice, which will intersect a bounded subset at finitely many places, and the Pythagorean diagonal distance tells you how to cover the whole set from balls centred at lattice points.

Comment: Many thanks. What I am actually looking for a proof by using Heine-Borel for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh, You have updated your answer. thanks